# Python signals and slots between classes

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am trying to get a Gui app in Python/PyQt to have a sliderDialog class to send a list of scalers to MainWindow via signals and emits .... but the following code does not work.  The sliders change value ... but the MainWindow does not see the signals, which I thought emit would inform MainWindow.  But no.   Help?  Oh - I know I have not set up to pass the scaler values, but since the signals don't work not pursuing this.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

OFFSET_Y = 15
OFFSET_X = 5
SPACER_Y = 20
SPACER_X = 50
switch = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 18.0]

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    sliderUpdate = QtCore.SIGNAL('sliderUpdate()')

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        sdlg = SliderDialog(self, 5)
        sdlg.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('sliderUpdate'), self.scalers)
        sdlg.show()

    def scalers(self) :
        print "In scalers of MainWindow!"

class SliderDialog(QtGui.QDialog) :

    sliderMoved  = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__( self, parent, dataCount ) :
        super(SliderDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        sliderLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        sliderLayout.addStretch()

        self.slider = []
        self.sliderLabel = []
        for i in range(dataCount) :

            s = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
            s.setMinimum(0)
            s.setMaximum(len(switch)-1)
            s.setTickInterval(1)
            s.setSingleStep(1)
            s.move(170, OFFSET_Y+30 + 3*SPACER_Y*i)
            s.sliderReleased.connect(self.sliderMoved)

            sl = QtGui.QLabel("Scaling to : 1.0", self)
            sl.move(5, OFFSET_Y+30 + 3*SPACER_Y*i)

            self.slider.append(s)
            self.sliderLabel.append(sl)

            sliderLayout.addWidget(self.slider[i])
            sliderLayout.addWidget(self.sliderLabel[i])

    def sliderMoved(self) :
        for i, slides in enumerate(self.slider) :
            scaler = slides.sliderPosition()
            self.sliderLabel[i].setText("Scaling to: {}".format(switch[scaler]))
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('sliderUpdate'))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: you've defined both a signal and a slot in `SliderDialog` called `sliderMoved` and appear to be mixing old-style and new style syntax for signals and slots.

Comment: SliderMoved was for only the SliderDialog to handle events.  Are you saying that caused problems with signals between the classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your put parameter of '`connect`' wrong;

```
bool QObject.connect (QObject, SIGNAL(), callable, Qt.ConnectionType = Qt.AutoConnection)
```

Parameter:

```
1. QObject  : Source object to receive emit signal

2. SIGNAL() : Signal name

3. callable : Callable do your want go it then have signal from source object

4. (Optional)
```

To fix them, please change right parameter in right position.

From;

```
sdlg.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('sliderUpdate'), self.scalers)
```

To;

```
self.connect(sdlg, QtCore.SIGNAL('sliderUpdate'), self.scalers)
```

---

**Reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#connect-2

---

**LAST EDITED 18 / 8/ 2014 11 : 37** : Add full code;

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

OFFSET_Y = 15
OFFSET_X = 5
SPACER_Y = 20
SPACER_X = 50
switch = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 18.0]

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    sliderUpdate = QtCore.SIGNAL('sliderUpdate()')

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        sdlg = SliderDialog(self, 5)
        self.connect(sdlg, QtCore.SIGNAL('sliderUpdate'), self.scalers)
        sdlg.show()

    def scalers(self) :
        print "In scalers of MainWindow!"

class SliderDialog(QtGui.QDialog) :

    sliderMoved  = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__( self, parent, dataCount ) :
        super(SliderDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        sliderLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        sliderLayout.addStretch()

        self.slider = []
        self.sliderLabel = []
        for i in range(dataCount) :

            s = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
            s.setMinimum(0)
            s.setMaximum(len(switch)-1)
            s.setTickInterval(1)
            s.setSingleStep(1)
            s.move(170, OFFSET_Y+30 + 3*SPACER_Y*i)
            s.sliderReleased.connect(self.sliderMoved)

            sl = QtGui.QLabel("Scaling to : 1.0", self)
            sl.move(5, OFFSET_Y+30 + 3*SPACER_Y*i)

            self.slider.append(s)
            self.sliderLabel.append(sl)

            sliderLayout.addWidget(self.slider[i])
            sliderLayout.addWidget(self.sliderLabel[i])

    def sliderMoved(self) :
        for i, slides in enumerate(self.slider) :
            scaler = slides.sliderPosition()
            self.sliderLabel[i].setText("Scaling to: {}".format(switch[scaler]))
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('sliderUpdate'))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Regards,

Comment: Well, that makes some sense. But unfortunately that modification to the code did not correct it. I do not see MainWindow invoke scalers and thus print a message.  Arigatoo

Comment: Ummm...,　I think it should be solve (Or I miss something ?). Please run my modify code to see what is different. Thanks. (Arigatoo -> ありがと)

Comment: 'How to pass the list values?' Answer: Your just get all value in slider position and put in emit just like your do it. 'self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('sliderUpdate'), listsValue)' and do forget to pass it to destination method 'def scalers(self, listsValue) :'.